# How can I create a time delay in c++ for a metro app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using visual studio 2013 for windows and compiling a windows 8.1 app. After a button is clicked, I have an action that changes some text on the screen, and I need it to repeatedly change that text about 100 times. I am trying to do some sort of asynchronous delay so that even as I continue to loop around updating the text, the frame updates so the user can see the text changing.

What is the best way to do this? I am trying to use Task.Delay, but I am having trouble figuring out how to declare the task to run my function, void update_logo().

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for dely in your method

> await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

hope this will help u.